# Random normal matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, random, tensorflow2.0

I have a matrix of mean values `M` and a matrix of standard deviations `D`, both of same size. I want to sample a matrix of random normal values `A`, such that the entry `A[i,j]` follows a normal distribution with mean `M[i,j]` and standard deviation `D[i,j]`.

From the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal?version=stable) I see that `tf.random.normal` only takes scalar mean and standard deviation.

I know I can write a loop and sample each element. But I think this will be slow.

Is there a better way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the elements of the desired random matrix are independently distributed. What you are trying to do can be achieved with:

```py
random_matrix = tf.random.normal([num_rows, num_cols]) * D + M
```

The `*` and `+` operators in the line above are overloaded to TensorFlow's element-wise multiply and add operations.

This uses this property of Gaussian distribution: if the unit Gaussian (`N(0, 1)`) is scaled by a factor `d` and shifted by a constant `m`, the Gaussian becomes `N(m, d)`.